# Phpmyadmin : how to copy a row from a table to another?

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

Instead of doing never end copy past between 2 joomla 2.5 website (I want to copy past their modul and articles)

Phpmyadmin :
How can I copy past a single or multiple row (article, module) from one jrm_content to jasso_content (they have both exactly the same colons type)

I know how to select rows and to import them, but after...? (I changed the id are different exept for some the  Asset ID is it a problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with queries like this?

```
INSERT INTO tableNew
            (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
            (
              SELECT
                    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
              FROM tableOld
            )
```

Comment: Well that look pretty interesting I ll try ! I ll tell you... Thanks a lot dear unknown !

Comment: Alternatively, PMA allows to copy/rename tables under 'Operations' tab.

Comment: Thank you for your help JA!

I was trying to find a solution for the error given by php myadmin but without success!
So here is the error message:

debug : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'fulltext, state, sectionid, mask, catid, created, created_by, created_by_alias, ' at line 2{"success":false,"error":"


Once again, thanks for your help JA!

Comment: I am look under operation tab, and there is indeed a copy database to but I can't find out how to select a specific row !

Comment: No Problem at all.. I think the error is due to the name "fulltext". As far as I am concerned, you can't use reserved word without quotation. How about removing that word and give it another go. It should be pretty straight forward query and I use that all the time for copying partial records. Good luck.

Comment: It works like a charm! I feel very dumb, this last solution was just so simple !  I just have one last question:

what should I add after ' where id= ' to be able to insert several rows at once, for the 2 examples below:
- id 777 + 782 + 786
- id 777 to id 790
Thanks so much for your help, for your time and for your patience!

Comment: Who knows all the reserved words!
1. If you like to filter some specific rows.. WHERE id IN (777,782,786).

2. For a range of rows.. WHERE (id>776) AND (id<791)..

Feel free to accept the answer of you think it helped ;)

Comment: Thanks so much JA! You are making my migration from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5 for my websites so easy! Your help is very precious to me! Thanks for being so patient with me!

Comment: Answer accepted! This is definitely so helpful!!! Thanks for the range of rows, I was trying to find it, but my friend google isn't as helpfull as you are ;-)!

Comment: You can also add a WHERE clause to the select statement to limit the rows being inserted, in case you do not want them all.

Comment: the problems with this are: **1)** you have to type the names of the columns (maybe I have a table with 20 columns) ... **2)** what about if I want to copy 1 row from a table on my local machine to a table on my webserver ... ... ... ...

Answer (score 0):

```
select from tablename where table name.primary key = table name.foreign key

<?php
$sname=$_POST['srname'];
      $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot Connect to the database!");
         mysql_select_db("human_resource",$link) or die ("Cannot select the database!");
         $query="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  fname='$sname'";
         $resource=mysql_query($query,$link);
         echo "
        <table align=\"center\" border=\"1\">
        <tr>
        <td><b>FName</b></td> <td><b>lname</b></td><td><b></b></td><td><b>Department</b></td></tr> ";
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($resource))
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$result[1]."</td><td>".$result[2]."</td><td>".$result[3]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```